# Autofocus e Required em campos ocultos por javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, div

Tenho um campo para selecionar outros dois campos. Quando mostra o campo situação esconde a outra div e vice versa, isso está funcionando perfeitamente. 
Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para dar um autofocus required quando o campo selecionado estiver visível, pois, já tentei colocar o comando direto na div e acontece que com isso eu inutilizo o botão pesquisar, pois, como os dois campos estão requisitando algo escrito acaba não funcionando. Segue o meu código.

```html
 <!--Script que esconde e mostra Divs-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
                id('tipo').onchange = function(){
                    if( this.value=="" || this.value=="contrato" || this.value=="cliente" || this.value=="cpf" || this.value=="numero" || this.value=="solicitante" )
                        id('filtro').style.display = 'block';
                    else
                        id('filtro').style.display = 'none';

                    if( this.value=="situacao" )
                        id('seletor').style.display = 'block';
                    else
                        id('seletor').style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
            function id(el){
                return document.getElementById(el);
            }
        </script>
        <!--Fim Script que esconde e mostra Divs-->

        <!--Campo Tipo-->
        <form method="get" action="pesquisas.php">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="input-group col-lg-12">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </div>
                        <select required autofocus class="form-control" name="tipo" id="tipo">
                            <option value="">SELECIONAR</option>
                            <option value="situacao">SITUAÇÃO</option>
                            <option value="contrato">CONTRATO</option>
                            <option value="cliente">CLIENTE</option>
                            <option value="cpf">CPF</option>
                            <option value="numero">NÚMERO</option>
                            <option value="solicitante">SOLICITANTE</option>
                        </select></form></div></div>
<!--Fim Campo Tipo-->

<!--Campo Situaçao-->
<div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-4" >
    <select type="text" class="form-control" name="seletor" id="seletor" style="display: none">
        <option value="">SELECIONAR</option>
        <option value="solicitada">SOLICITADA</option>
        <option value="portada">PORTADA</option>
        <option value="cancelada">CANCELADA</option>
        <option value="erro">ERRO</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!--Fim Campo Situaçao-->

<!--Campo de pesquisa escrita-->
<div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-4" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="filtro" id="filtro"></div>
<!--Fim Campo de pesquisa escrita-->

<input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="btn btn-primary"><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando o elemento for visível, defina o atributo `required` como **true**; quando for invisível, defina como **false**.

O `autofocus` só vai funcionar no carregamento da página, portanto use o método `.focus()` para focar no elemento.

> Fiz uma pequena alteração na estrutura do seu HTML porque o botão de
>   `submit` estava fora do `form` e tinha umas `div`s fechadas de forma
>   errada.

**Veja:**

```js
window.onload = function(){
   id('tipo').onchange = function(){
      if( this.value=="" || this.value=="contrato" || this.value=="cliente" || this.value=="cpf" || this.value=="numero" || this.value=="solicitante" )
         id('filtro').style.display = 'block',
         id('filtro').required = true,
         id('filtro').focus();
      else
         id('filtro').style.display = 'none',
         id('filtro').required = false;
   
      if( this.value=="situacao" )
         id('seletor').style.display = 'block',
         id('seletor').required = true,
         id('seletor').focus();
      else
         id('seletor').style.display = 'none',
         id('seletor').required = false;
   }
}

function id(el){
   return document.getElementById(el);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form method="get" action="pesquisas.php">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <div class="input-group col-lg-12">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </div>
            <select required autofocus class="form-control" name="tipo" id="tipo">
               <option value="">SELECIONAR</option>
               <option value="situacao">SITUAÇÃO</option>
               <option value="contrato">CONTRATO</option>
               <option value="cliente">CLIENTE</option>
               <option value="cpf">CPF</option>
               <option value="numero">NÚMERO</option>
               <option value="solicitante">SOLICITANTE</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--Fim Campo Tipo-->
   
   <!--Campo Situaçao-->
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-4" >
      <select type="text" class="form-control" name="seletor" id="seletor" style="display: none">
         <option value="">SELECIONAR</option>
         <option value="solicitada">SOLICITADA</option>
         <option value="portada">PORTADA</option>
         <option value="cancelada">CANCELADA</option>
         <option value="erro">ERRO</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <!--Fim Campo Situaçao-->
   
   <!--Campo de pesquisa escrita-->
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-4" >
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="filtro" id="filtro">
   </div>
   <!--Fim Campo de pesquisa escrita-->
   
   <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="btn btn-primary"><br><br>
</form>
```

**Uma forma um pouco mais otimizada do script:**

```
window.onload = function(){
   id('tipo').onchange = function(){
      var filtro = id('filtro');
      var seletor = id('seletor');

      if( !this.value || this.value.match(/^(contrato|cliente|cpf|numero|solicitante)$/) )
         filtro.style.display = 'block',
         filtro.required = true,
         filtro.focus();
      else
         filtro.style.display = 'none',
         filtro.required = false;

      if( this.value=="situacao" )
         seletor.style.display = 'block',
         seletor.required = true,
         seletor.focus();
      else
         seletor.style.display = 'none',
         seletor.required = false;
   }
}

function id(el){
   return document.getElementById(el);
}
```

### Usando jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#tipo").change(function(){
      var filtro = $('#filtro');
      var seletor = $('#seletor');
      
      if( !$(this).val() || $(this).val().match(/^(contrato|cliente|cpf|numero|solicitante)$/) )
         filtro
         .show()
         .attr('required', true)
         .focus();
      else
         filtro
         .hide()
         .attr('required', false);

      if( $(this).val() == "situacao")
         seletor
         .show()
         .attr('required', true)
         .focus();
      else
         seletor
         .hide()
         .attr('required', false);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form method="get" action="pesquisas.php">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <div class="input-group col-lg-12">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </div>
            <select required autofocus class="form-control" name="tipo" id="tipo">
               <option value="">SELECIONAR</option>
               <option value="situacao">SITUAÇÃO</option>
               <option value="contrato">CONTRATO</option>
               <option value="cliente">CLIENTE</option>
               <option value="cpf">CPF</option>
               <option value="numero">NÚMERO</option>
               <option value="solicitante">SOLICITANTE</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--Fim Campo Tipo-->
   
   <!--Campo Situaçao-->
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-4" >
      <select type="text" class="form-control" name="seletor" id="seletor" style="display: none">
         <option value="">SELECIONAR</option>
         <option value="solicitada">SOLICITADA</option>
         <option value="portada">PORTADA</option>
         <option value="cancelada">CANCELADA</option>
         <option value="erro">ERRO</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <!--Fim Campo Situaçao-->
   
   <!--Campo de pesquisa escrita-->
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-4" >
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="filtro" id="filtro">
   </div>
   <!--Fim Campo de pesquisa escrita-->
   
   <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="btn btn-primary"><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Amigo nem sei como agradecer. Era exatamente o que eu matei a cabeça para entender. Sou novo em programação. Mto obrigado.

Comment: é nois na fita +1. Quando aparece o segundo select clicando em situação, a palavra desse segundo select fica cortada

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo opa! rsrs.. Isso tem a ver com a classe do Bootstrap que ele tá usando. Não entrei nesse detalhe pq não tem muito a ver com a pergunta.

Comment: Foi o que pensei, tu é muito preguiça! kkk

Comment: @CarlosKhan É importantíssimo para a comunidade que você marque a resposta que mais lhe serviu com ✓ (se não sabe como fazer isso, dá uma olhada [nesta página deste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)). Ao marcar a resposta (apenas UMA delas) você está não apenas respeitando a forma de funcionamento do site como estimulando e recompensando quem se esforça em responder as suas perguntas. Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você pode usar o `focus()` e o `setAttribute("required", "")`, para fazer com que o campo SITUAÇÃO seja requirido e focado quando aparecer na tela. Verifique abaixo:

```js
window.onload = function(){
                id('tipo').onchange = function(){
                    if( this.value=="" || this.value=="contrato" || this.value=="cliente" || this.value=="cpf" || this.value=="numero" || this.value=="solicitante" ) {
                        id('filtro').style.display = 'block';
                        }
                    else {
                        id('filtro').style.display = 'none';
                        }

                    if( this.value=="situacao" ) {
                        id('seletor').style.display = 'block';
                        id('seletor').focus();
                        id('seletor').setAttribute("required", "");
                        }
                    else {
                        id('seletor').style.display = 'none';
                        }
                }
            }
            function id(el){
                return document.getElementById(el);
            }
```

```html
<form method="get" action="pesquisas.php">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="input-group col-lg-12">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </div>
                        <select required autofocus class="form-control" name="tipo" id="tipo">
                            <option value="">SELECIONAR</option>
                            <option value="situacao">SITUAÇÃO</option>
                            <option value="contrato">CONTRATO</option>
                            <option value="cliente">CLIENTE</option>
                            <option value="cpf">CPF</option>
                            <option value="numero">NÚMERO</option>
                            <option value="solicitante">SOLICITANTE</option>
                        </select></form></div></div>

<div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-4" >
    <select type="text" class="form-control" name="seletor" id="seletor" style="display: none">
        <option value="">SELECIONAR</option>
        <option value="solicitada">SOLICITADA</option>
        <option value="portada">PORTADA</option>
        <option value="cancelada">CANCELADA</option>
        <option value="erro">ERRO</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-4" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="filtro" id="filtro"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="btn btn-primary"><br><br>
```